# I need a loop that will add a number ( or subtract a number) every time there is a collision

Tags: livecode

I am doing this for school. I am adding to a preexisting program.

What I am trying to do is increase the fuel in the fuel label every time the fuel canister encounters my rocket ship. I have created a checkFuel command and I added it to the rocket ship movement so it will check every time the rocket ship moves and also at the end of the fuel canister movements.

The issue seems to be that since I an sending the fuel canister movement to me ever 50 milliseconds that it is adding more fuel if the canister and the rocket ship are still intersected. so instead of 50 fuel it is adding 150 to the fuel tally.

I am using the same code to subtract lives if an asteroid encounters the rocket ship but it will just subtract off all the lives and end the game after 1 collision.

```
`  // Getting the fuel canister moving 

command moveFuelCanister
   if sMoving then 
  set top of image "Fuel Canister.png" to top of image "Fuel Canister.png"+15

  if top of image "Fuel Canister.png" > 768 then 
       set the randomSeed to the long seconds
  put random(1024) into randomWidth
  set location of image "Fuel Canister.png" to  randomWidth,0  
 end if 

  send moveFuelCanister to me in 50 milliseconds 
   end if 
   checkFuel
 end moveFuelCanister

 //Checking if the ship hits the fuel  
command checkFuel
   if intersect(image "rocketshipUp", image "Fuel Canister.png" ,"pixels") \
    OR  intersect(image "rocketshipDown", image "Fuel Canister.png" ,"pixels") \
    OR intersect(image "rocketshipLeft", image "Fuel Canister.png" ,"pixels") \
    OR intersect(image "rocketshipRight", image "Fuel Canister.png" ,"pixels")
   then 
  add 50 to gFuelLevel
  put "Fuel Level:  " & gFuelLevel  into field "Fuellevellbl"
  end if 
end checkFuel `
```

Answer (score 0):

There's a few options to solve this. You can:

- reset the fuel canister to the top of the screen on first hit
- hide the fuel canister on first hit
- set a custom property on the fuel canister when it is hit

The last option makes the least change to the way your game works but without seeing *all* the code it's hard to tell exactly what you want to do.

Here's the last option:

```
command moveFuelCanister
   if sMoving then 
  set top of image "Fuel Canister.png" to top of image "Fuel Canister.png"+15

  if top of image "Fuel Canister.png" > 768 then 
       set the randomSeed to the long seconds
  put random(1024) into randomWidth
  set location of image "Fuel Canister.png" to  randomWidth,0 
  set the uHit of image "Fuel Canister.png" to false
 end if 

  send moveFuelCanister to me in 50 milliseconds 
   end if 
   checkFuel
 end moveFuelCanister

 //Checking if the ship hits the fuel  
command checkFuel
   if not the uHit of image "Fuel Canister.png" \
    and (intersect(image "rocketshipUp", image "Fuel Canister.png" ,"pixels") \
    OR  intersect(image "rocketshipDown", image "Fuel Canister.png" ,"pixels") \
    OR intersect(image "rocketshipLeft", image "Fuel Canister.png" ,"pixels") \
    OR intersect(image "rocketshipRight", image "Fuel Canister.png" ,"pixels"))
   then 
     set the uHit of image "Fuel Canister.png" to true

     add 50 to gFuelLevel
     put "Fuel Level:  " & gFuelLevel  into field "Fuellevellbl"
  end if 
end checkFuel
```

Other options might be changing the image to show an empty fuel canister falling after the hit.

Comment: So simple but so perfect. Reading this made me feel stupid. I know that it comes with experience but I should have thought of this myself but I was making it harder than it had to be. Thank you for taking the time to answer and to write a little code to assist.

Answer (score 0):

Another idea, use a script local variable to ensure just one fuel increase per hit...

```
//Checking if the ship hits the fuel 
local sAddFuel --** Use a script local var for checking collisions **
command checkFuel
   if intersect(image "rocketshipUp", image "Fuel Canister.png" ,"pixels") \
         OR  intersect(image "rocketshipDown", image "Fuel Canister.png" ,"pixels") \
         OR intersect(image "rocketshipLeft", image "Fuel Canister.png" ,"pixels") \
         OR intersect(image "rocketshipRight", image "Fuel Canister.png" ,"pixels") then
      add 1 to sAddFuel --** counts up for each intersect command **
   else
      put 0 into sAddFuel --** Resets back to zero when no intersect **
   end if

   if sAddFuel = 1 then --** Will only add fuel for 1st collision **
      add 50 to gFuelLevel
      put "Fuel Level:  " & gFuelLevel into field "Fuellevellbl"
   end if 
end checkFuel
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. I knew that posting on here would give me the answers that a Google search would not. Thank you again.